# Issues when initialising @Binding with other properties

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Unable to initialize a property along with a @Binding object

I've also tried to initialize it in the init( ) method of the struct

```
struct WorkoutCard: View {

       var numberOfWorkouts : [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]

       @State var beginWorkout :Bool = false

 var body: some View {
        ZStack {

       Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.black)

            if !self.beginWorkout {

    ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {

         HStack {


   ForEach(self.numberOfWorkouts.reversed(), id: \.self) { index in


           Card(index, beginWorkout: $beginWorkout)


            }
 }

                } }
          }
}


 }
```

// The view to be initialized

```
 struct Card: View {

var number : Int

@Binding var beginWorkout : Bool


    init(_ index: Int) {
        self.number = index
          }
  }
```

Error = Extra argument "beginWorkout" in call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call, you're missing `.self`:

```swift
Card(index, beginWorkout: self.$beginWorkout)
```

And your initializer is missing your beginWorkout parameter:

```swift
struct Card: View {

    var number : Int

    @Binding var beginWorkout : Bool

    init(_ index: Int, beginWorkout: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.number = index
        self._beginWorkout = beginWorkout
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!, I wasn't adding the Binding<Bool> parameter. I was adding only Bool as type in my previous attempts. It makes sense now.